# Run Javascript File from HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, scripting

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 to act as a web server, it all works. Within my HTML Code I have this line within the body:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='clock.js') }}"></script>
```

The 'clock.js' is a script for running a live clock which updates on the HTML web page. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I do all this and I get a constant error within the HTML Console which says:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>   clock.js (1,1)

Comment: Where is `clock.js` requested or used at `HTML` at Question? The stacksnippets renders expected result

Comment: a JS file is javascript, you can't have raw HTML in it (like <!DOCTYPE html>)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
```

correct:

```
if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i;}
```